# Let $r,s \in R$ where $R$ is a ring. Then $(mr)(ns)$ = $mn(rs)$ for all integers $m$ and $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The way I tried to proved it seemed to on a weaker version of what I was trying to prove in the first place. It is clearly true but it isn't obvious to me how to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $r, s\in R$, $m, n\in\mathbb{N}$ be given. Then
$$\begin{align*}
(mr)(ns) &= (r + \ldots + r)(s + \ldots + s)\text{ ($m$ and $n$ times, respectively)}\\
&= (r(s + \ldots + s) + \ldots + r(s + \ldots + s))\text{ by distributivity}\\
&= rs + \ldots + rs\text{ ($mn$ times) by distributivity}\\
&= mn(rs)
\end{align*}$$

Generalizing to $m, n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is straightforward.

It should be noted that we are freely using the associativity of $+$ without comment above.

Comment: Good answer. A remark: we're freely using associativity of addition here (depending on how rigorous you want to be in your proof).

Comment: Good point, edited to reflect that.